# Is it possible to overlap views with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

Say you had a screen that had 2 full size views in it (edge to edge, top to bottom, left to right) and the topmost view in the z-order had an alpha that made it partially transparent so that you could see the other view underneath it.

***Is there a way to describe this with AutoLayout constraints?***

I've tried simply taking both views and pinning them to left/right/top/bottom of their superview, but when I run it, they either end up in some random size/position, or are invisible altogether.

Attached here are 4 images...

- An image from Reveal showing a misplacement on a run.
- Beneath that is an image of my view hierarchy.
- The simulator, showing nothing where the maps should be.
- XCode pic of the constraints

Basically I have 2 maps... one from ArcGis and one from Google, and they need to both be full screen and overlap each other.

[image: Picture From Reveal]

[image: View Hierarchy]

[image: The Simulator]

[image: XCode Pic]

Comment: are you using code to autosize or storyboard? post your code or xib

Comment: I'm using Interface Builder on a nib... no storyboard, no code.